# Is there any way to use groupBy on a stream and send each substream to a different file?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

For example, if I am parsing a log that starts with a server name and I want to split it in a file for each server, is there a way of doing that without knowing how many servers there are?

```
FileIO.fromPath(Paths.get("in.log"))
   .via(Framing.delimiter(ByteString("\n".getBytes), maximumFrameLength = 4000)).map(_.utf8String)
   .map(_.span(_ == ' '))
   .groupBy(100, _._1)
```

This would result in a substream of (filename, logged), but I don't know if it's possible to connect each substream to a separate sink.

Comment: Please have a look at this: [Akka Content-based Substreaming](http://blog.genuine.com/2018/04/akka-content-based-substreaming/). I think it will not be that complicated to modify to do what you want.

Comment: @m4gic thanks, unfortunately I think that this would only work if you can fit the whole data in memory, since it accumulates all the messages and writes them all to disk one the whole stream finishes.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to further process the log lines? If not, you can just use a custom sink.

```
def writeLineByServerName(line: String): Unit = {
  val name = getServerNameFromLine(line)
  // either create a new output stream or get an existing one from
  // a pool. you may need to manage your resources to limit open
  // buffers
  val outputStream = getOutputStream(name)
  outputStream.write(line)
}

FileIO.fromPath(Paths.get("in.log"))
   .via(Framing.delimiter(ByteString("\n".getBytes), maximumFrameLength = 4000)).map(_.utf8String)
   .map(_.span(_ == ' '))
   .to(Sink.foreach[String](writeLineByServerName))
```

Otherwise, you can read the file twice. The first read will figure out how many servers there are.